# Options when contracted services being performed without reasonable care or skill

Tags: contract-law, united-kingdom, england-and-wales

In England, under the 2015 Consumer Rights Act, services have to be performed with reasonable care and skill.

So what is a good, but legal, course of action when it becomes apparent during the supply of services that the supplier is not using reasonable care and skill, and you don’t want them to continue making a bad job worse?

For example, let’s say the contract was to paint exterior windows and doors. The windows were painted first, the paint is uneven, lots of drips, paint on glass, and where the contractor has attempted to sort this out the glass is scratched. The contractor wants payment as per the schedule, and wants to go on to paint the doors.

[According to the UK’s consumer association Which?](https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/how-to-complain-if-you-re-unhappy-with-building-work-aWG3g5O4RZCh), withholding payment would be breach of contract. So what are the options?

(Note that the linked article seems to be suggesting options at the end of the contract, whereas I am specifically trying to avoid more sub-standard work being done.)

Comment: Why are you unhappy with the options in the linked article?